# Codeigniter: Can't get images from folder after uploading

Tags: php, codeigniter

i just learning codeigniter, and i find some tutorials for uploading and getting images from folder,and Function do_upload () works and creates directories, but the function get_images () does not work

This is my model:

```
    var $gallery_path;
    var $gallery_path_url;

    function Gallery_model()
    {

        $this->gallery_path = realpath(APPPATH .'../images');
        $this->gallery_path_url = base_url().'images/';
    }

        function get_images(){
        $files = scandir($this->gallery_path.'thumbs');
        $files = array_diff($files, array('.', '..', 'thumbs'));

        $images = array();

        foreach ($files as $file){
            $images[] = array(
                    'url' => $this->gallery_path_url . $file,
                    'thumb_url' => $this->gallery_path_url . 'thumbs/' . $file
                );
        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
  function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('gallery_model');

        if($this->input->post('upload')){
            $this->gallery_model->do_upload();
        }

        $data['images'] = $this->gallery_model->get_images();

        $this->load->view("gallery", $data);
    }
```

View:

```
<div id="gallery">
    <?php if(isset($images) && count($images)): 
        foreach ($images as $image):
     ?>
        <div class="thumb">
            <a href="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo $image['thumb_url']; ?>" />
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; else: ?>
        <div id="blank_gallery">Please upload an image</div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div id="upload">
    <?php
        echo form_open_multipart('gallery');
        echo form_upload('userfile');
        echo form_submit('upload', 'Upload');
        echo form_close();
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say it's not working, what do you mean? It doesn't get the images at all? Wrong path? Wrong number of images? Please be more specific.

Comment: It doesn't get images at all. I guess is problem in view or model, controller should be okey.

Comment: Ok, you upload images in images folder, but then you scan the directory imagesthumbs? Do you have such directory? If yes, does it have any images inside?

Comment: yes they have images, original one and resized image. One folder is images for original pic, and the second one folder is thumbs for resized pic

Comment: Oh sorry man i resolve a problem. problem is in the model.

i need return $images in the end

Comment: Oh well. Most of the times, such problems are solved just by talking with someone else to give a short break to your brain. Glad you find it.

Comment: Me to, I spent half a day for this problem. Thank's for your time